# Sample webserver is not accessible on external ip of GCP VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

I have created a sample webserver using python in GCP VM Using below code.

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import time

hostName = "localhost"
serverPort = 5500

class MyServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<html><head><title>https://pythonbasics.org</title></head>", "utf-8"))
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<p>Request: %s</p>" % self.path, "utf-8"))
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<body>", "utf-8"))
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<p>This is an example web server.</p>", "utf-8"))
        self.wfile.write(bytes("</body></html>", "utf-8"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    webServer = HTTPServer((hostName, serverPort), MyServer)
    print("Server started http://%s:%s" % (hostName, serverPort))

    try:
        webServer.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

    webServer.server_close()
    print("Server stopped.")
```

I can access this server on the VM using the command.

```
user@instance1:~$ curl  http://localhost:5500
<html><head><title>https://pythonbasics.org</title></head><p>Request: /</p><body><p>This is an example web server.</p></body></html>
```

I have created a firewall rule to allow access from all source ips. But not able to access using external ip. I have also tried from external browser.
[Firewall rule screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFRZn.png). [Allow HTTP(S)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2T3yr.png).Here the external ip is 34.122.198.62

```
user@instance1:~$ curl  http://34.122.198.62:5500/
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 34.122.198.62 port 5500: Connection refused
```

Could you please help in resolve the issue? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Running the server with `python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` resolved the issue.